# Sideways corner markers (CSS)

Tags: css

I have an HTML page with many photos listed on it. I am looking for some help on how to do the CSS so that some photos have a top-corner "marker" like the red stripe here called "Featured" --

http://www.logospire.com/logos/3922

[image]

I could have googled for what this is, but I don't know the keywords. Would love any tips and pointers.

Comment: Try searching for the :before selector - might be what you're looking for!

Comment: @Hannele im interested to know how this would help?

Comment: Also, if you're using a browser like Chrome, you can right-click on an object, and hit "Select Element" right at the bottom of the list. This will make a small window on the bottom with the HTML used to create the item highlighted, and any CSS tricks and classes on the right. That will help you recreate something on your own!

Comment: @Hannele I honeslty think you have misunderstood the question completely.

Comment: @JonTaylor Possibly true, but I've seen `:before `and `:after` selectors used to create effects like [this](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-image-styles-part-2) and [this](http://css-tricks.com/tabs-with-round-out-borders/)

Comment: @Hannele Of course it can be used in the solution, but that's not what makes it work. It helps achieving it without extra markup for sure. You could even use Substring matching attribute selectors, it sounds cool, but still it is not what makes the solution work.

Comment: @bažmegakapa True. Note, though, I wasn't trying to present the :before selector _as_ a complete solution - just as a helpful direction to search in, as the OP's mentioned he wasn't sure what to search for.

Comment: @Hannele In that case, you sent him the wrong way :).

Comment: @bažmegakapa I acknowledge, background-image and z-index is a much cleaner solution.

Comment: @Hannele Don't want to get any deeper into this. You can use `:before` for any type of solution - be it the simple image solution, or the CSS3 rotate (which is much nicer, but not supported in every browser). You can use `:before` and `:after` for thousands of other things - it saves you extra markup, that's all and that's why we love it. I only wanted to point out that in itself, it does help getting closer to the solution in this specific problem in any way.

Comment: @bažmegakapa I do realise that I didn't give the most helpful advice, as JonTaylor also pointed out, which is why I subsequently gave a couple examples of effects I've seen that use the selectors. Again, I didn't have a complete answer, but I didn't pretend to have one either (hence, comment). I'm trying to _agree_ with you, here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the page you linked, it is solved with a `background-image`, so it's simply an image. You can use Chrome Inspector / Firebug / IE Developer Tools / DragonFly / etc. to inspect the element.

**HTML**:

```
<a id="featured" href="/?sort=featured"></a>
```

**CSS**:

```css
#featured {
    display: block;
    width: 94px;
    height: 78px;
    background: url(/images/featured_bg.png) no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    top: -2px;
    left: -2px;
}
```

You could also use [CSS3 Transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms) (specifically [Rotation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform#rotate)) to achieve something like this.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much everyone and especially bazmegakapa. What a community this is! And appreciate the suggestion of "Inspect Element" in CHrome. Love it.

Answer (score 1):

http://fusioncold.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/text-rotate-with-css.html

You can start off with that link, and google further keywords if you need more help

Answer (score 1):

You just place your main image in a div with position relative on it and a z-index of say "1".

Then you place the small corner image in the div too and make it position absolute with top:0 left:0 and a z-index of say "2".

If you want it to sit slightly out of the box as in the example make it slightly negative values for left and top positioning.